# pdo_module.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl php_pdo_register_driver(struct pdo_driver_t *)"

Tags: php, pdo, php-extension, php-internals

LINK: unresolved external symbol :php_pdo_register_driver

I'm writing a PHP PDO ext demo with PHP7.2.21, when I tried to register my ext on PDO, I got an error.

```
PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION(pdo_my_mysql) {
#ifdef _PDO_CDATA_TRACE_
  PRINT("invoke PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION");
#endif // _PDO_MY_TRACE_
  return php_pdo_register_driver(&pdo_my_mysql_driver);
}
```

```
"cl.exe" /D COMPILE_DL_PDO_MY_MYSQL /D PDO_MY_MYSQL_EXPORTS=1 /nologo /I . /I main /I Zend /I TSRM /I ext /D _WINDOWS /D WINDOWS=1 /D ZEND_WIN32=1 /D PHP_WIN32=1 /D WIN32 /D _MBCS /W3 /D _USE_MATH_DEFINES /FD /wd4996 /Qspectre /guard:cf /Zc:inline /Zc:__cplusplus /MP /LD /MD /W3 /Ox /D NDebug /D NDEBUG /D ZEND_WIN32_FORCE_INLINE /GF /D ZEND_DEBUG=0 /D ZTS=1 /I "D:\wrappers\php\php-sdk7.2.21\phpmaster\vc15\x64\deps\include" /D FD_SETSIZE=256 /FoD:\wrappers\php\php-sdk7.2.21\phpmaster\vc15\x64\php-7.2.21-src\x64\Release_TS\Dev\RSSBus\v19\Release\ProviderMySQL\php\ /FpD:\wrappers\php\php-sdk7.2.21\phpmaster\vc15\x64\php-7.2.21-src\x64\Release_TS\Dev\RSSBus\v19\Release\ProviderMySQL\php\ /FRD:\wrappers\php\php-sdk7.2.21\phpmaster\vc15\x64\php-7.2.21-src\x64\Release_TS\Dev\RSSBus\v19\Release\ProviderMySQL\php\ /FdD:\wrappers\php\php-sdk7.2.21\phpmaster\vc15\x64\php-7.2.21-src\x64\Release_TS\Dev\RSSBus\v19\Release\ProviderMySQL\php\ /c C:\Dev\RSSBus\v19\Release\ProviderMySQL\php\pdo_module.cpp
pdo_module.cpp
        rc /nologo  /I . /I main /I Zend /I TSRM /I ext /n /fo D:\wrappers\php\php-sdk7.2.21\phpmaster\vc15\x64\php-7.2.21-src\x64\Release_TS\php_pdo_my_mysql.dll.res /d FILE_DESCRIPTION="\"php_pdo_my_mysql.dll\"" /d FILE_NAME="\"php_pdo_my_mysql.dll\"" /d URL="\"http://www.php.net\"" /d INTERNAL_NAME="\"PDO_MY_MYSQL extension\"" /d THANKS_GUYS="\"\"" win32\build\template.rc
   Creating library D:\wrappers\php\php-sdk7.2.21\phpmaster\vc15\x64\php-7.2.21-src\x64\Release_TS\php_pdo_my_mysql.lib and object D:\wrappers\php\php-sdk7.2.21\phpmaster\vc15\x64\php-7.2.21-src\x64\Release_TS\php_pdo_my_mysql.exp
pdo_module.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl php_pdo_register_driver(struct pdo_driver_t *)" (?php_pdo_register_driver@@YAHPEAUpdo_driver_t@@@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl zm_startup_pdo_my_mysql(int,int)" (?zm_startup_pdo_my_mysql@@YAHHH@Z)
D:\wrappers\php\php-sdk7.2.21\phpmaster\vc15\x64\php-7.2.21-src\x64\Release_TS\php_pdo_my_mysql.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX64\x64\link.exe"' : return code '0x460'
Stop.
```

This is the command I ran to compile the pdo

```
extbuildconf --add-modules-dir=ext_folder
configure --enable-cli --enable-pdo --enable-pdo_my_mysql
nmake
```

Comment: This is the command I ran to compile the pdo ext```buildconf --add-modules-dir=ext_folder```,```configure --enable-cli --enable-pdo --enable-pdo_my_mysql```,```nmake```

Comment: Do you `include "ext/pdo/php_pdo_driver.h"`?

Comment: Yes, these are the includes:```#include <php.h>
#include <php_ini.h>
#include <ext/standard/info.h>
#include <pdo/php_pdo.h>
#include <pdo/php_pdo_driver.h>
#include "php_pdo_module.h"
#include "php_pdo_module_int.h"```. Moreover, I fount how to avoid this error, change the file name from pdo_module.cpp to pdo_module.c. I'm confused. What should I do to prevent the rename?

Comment: If you're writing C, stick with the .c file extension. If you're writing C++, then you have to put the include(s) in an extern "C" block:
````
extern "C" {
#include "php_pdo_driver.h"
}
````

Comment: Bingo, thanks for saving me. I added the extern "C" block to the includes, it works.```extern "C" {
#include <php.h>
#include <php_ini.h>
#include <ext/standard/info.h>
#include <pdo/php_pdo.h>
#include <pdo/php_pdo_driver.h>
}```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @cmb.

I put the includes in an extern "C" block, and it worked.

Previous version:

```
#include <php.h>
#include <php_ini.h>
#include <ext/standard/info.h>
#include <pdo/php_pdo.h>
#include <pdo/php_pdo_driver.h>
```

Working version:

```
extern "C" {
#include <php.h>
#include <php_ini.h>
#include <ext/standard/info.h>
#include <pdo/php_pdo.h>
#include <pdo/php_pdo_driver.h>
}
```